# How to init a class const static struct using some statement in C++

Tags: c++, stl

There is a const static std::map belonging to a class. Is there a kind of formation which can form the following code :

```
// file A.h
class A {
   public:
           const static std::map<std::string, int> m_name2code;
   public:
           static int getCode(std::string name);
   private:
           const static char *name[3];
}

// file A.cpp
const char * A::name = {
            "hello", "the", "world" }
for (int index = 0; index < 3; ++index) {
        m_name2code.insert(std::string(name[i]), i+1);
}
```

As the code above, I was wondering if there is some syntax to use control-statement to init the class-const-static member?

Thank you very much...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Control statement based on what?

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it to.   Either the static map is `const`, so must be initialised where it is defined, or it is left non`const` so it can be initialised in subsequent code statements.   The two are largely mutually exclusive.    If you must have a `public` map accessible (which strikes me as a shocking design decision, BTW) set it up as a `const` reference that refers to a `private static` but non-`const` member - then initialise that private member when needed.

Comment: @Peter: see my answer on how to initialize a `const` data structure without a reference being around. With initializer lists the map can also be initialized straight away. Of course, once initialized it becomes immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’d separate the initialization into two phases:

1. Build the map in a function and return the result.
2. Initialize the `static` variable from the result of the function.

For example:

```
namespace {
    std::map<std::string, int> build_map() {
        std::map<std::string, int> rc;
        const char * A::name = { "hello", "the", "world" };
        for (int index = 0; index < 3; ++index) {
            rc.emplace(std::string(name[index]), index+1);
        }
        return rc;
    }
}
std::map<std::string, int> const A::m_name2code = build_map();
```

If you want to go extra fancy you can even initialize a map (although not a `std::map`) at compile time using `constexpr` (see, e.g., my [CppCon](http://cppcon.org) 2016 presentation: [Constant Fun](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xWmdcvTedbc)).

Comment: Thank you very much, you perfectly solved my question.